# how to enable button UIAlertController when the user has scrolled down?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Is there a way to set-up the UIAlertController to allow the user to press an ok button only when they have scrolled down through the text?

If I use the message field in the UIAlertController to show (multi-line) text and add a UITextField, I'm already part of the way there.  It would need a way to get the textField to act like a checkbox.

```
let termsOfService = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sem arcu, vestibulum non aliquam sit amet, pellentesque eu urna. Sed posuere eu metus eu dapibus. Praesent vitae vulputate felis. Donec erat elit, ullamcorper nec lectus eu, sagittis faucibus nibh. Etiam ligula elit, dignissim fringilla ornare vel, eleifend sit amet enim. Vestibulum ac cursus ipsum. Curabitur augue nisl, ultrices vitae massa quis, auctor faucibus dui. Integer ut est velit. Cras felis purus, dictum id iaculis id, ultricies nec dui. Duis sollicitudin nisi vel massa egestas trirtique. Fusce tempus gravida tellus a rhoncus. Integer id sapien non purus efficitur aliquam vitae varius lectus. In malesuada felis egestas neque pretium condime"
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Agreement", message: termsOfService, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
    textField.text = "I agree"
}
let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (action) in
    print(action)
}
alert.addAction(okayAction)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Cancel",
            style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
                print(action)
        }
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You would have to implement a look a like AlertController yourself.

Comment: Do you have an example?  Especially the code lines to enable button when scrolled down?